# Handling defunct deferred (timeout) messages?

Tags: rebus, rebus-azureservicebus

I am new to Rebus and am trying to get up to speed with some patterns we currently use in Azure Logic Apps. The current target implementation would use Azure Service Bus with Saga storage preferably in Cosmos DB (still investigating that sample implementation). Maybe even use Rebus Mongo DB with Cosmos DB using the Mongo DB API (not sure if that is possible though).

One major use case we have is an event/timeout pattern, and after doing some reading of samples/forums/Stack Overflow this is not uncommon. The tricky part is that our Sagas would behave more as a Finite State Machine vs. a Directed Acyclic Graph. This mainly happens because dates are externally changed and therefore timeouts for events change.

The `Defer()` method does not return a timeout identifier, which we assume is an implementation restriction (Azure Service Bus returns a long). Since we must ignore timeouts that had been scheduled for an event which has now shifted in time, we see a way of having those timeouts "ignored" (since they cannot be cancelled) as follows:

- Use a `Dictionary<string, Guid>` in our own `SagaData`-derived base class, where the key is some derivative of the timeout message type, and the Guid is the identifier given to the timeout message when it was created. I don't believe this needs to be a concurrent dictionary but that is why I am here...
- On receipt of the event message, remove the corresponding timeout message type key from the above dictionary;
- On receipt of the timeout message:

  - Ignore if it's timeout message type key is not present or the Guid does not match the dictionary key/value; else
  - Process. We could also remove the dictionary key at this point as well.
- When event rescheduling occurs, simply add the timeout message type/Guid dictionary entry, or update the Guid with the new timeout message Guid.

Is this on the right track, or is there a more 'correct' way of handling defunct timeout (deferred) messages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are on the right track

> I don't believe this needs to be a concurrent dictionary but that is why I am here...

Rebus lets your saga handler work on its own copy of the saga data (using optimistic  concurrency), so you're free to model the saga data as if it's being only being accessed by one at a time.